# Google Maps API 3 - searching the map like on maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I appear to be missing something here so I'm hoping someone can point at the place I should be looking. 
I have a google map on my HTML page that I am manipulating to load markers and add markers on click, now I want a search box so people can search for the general area before they click to add a location.
I am reading the Google Maps API [developers guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) but I can't seem to find how to do this..
I know I must be missing it so can someone point me in the right direction!

Thanks so much in advance and sorry for the silly question!

Bex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be Geocoding that you'll want... It's the process of asking google for the location.

Here is a [great example of Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html) provided in the Sample code.

Looking in the developer's guide for Geocoding will give you plenty of results; I agree with you though, it can be a little difficult to find what you want. It's under the "Services" section in the guide

Comment: Oh.. I thought it'd be something like google.maps.Map.Search(something...) and then you'd just apply it to the map or something...  No wonder  couldn't find it!

Comment: I just trawled through the sample code until I found one that emulated what I was trying to achieve. Please can you accept my answer? Cheers

Comment: Now why didn't I think of doing that! Thanks anyway!